# Webclient complicated query generates java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: rest, get, illegalargumentexception, spring-webclient

I'm trying to send a complex query
http://myserver:1234/api/v1/query?query=(sum(cluster_health{Component='kafka'}))/count(cluster_health{Component='kafka'})";

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'Component=\'kafka\''
```

I read about this Exception and found that

1. in [Using RestTemplate in Spring. Exception- Not enough variables available to expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819210/using-resttemplate-in-spring-exception-not-enough-variables-available-to-expan)
   It was discussed to use
   POST to handle complex queries.
   How do I put the query in request body?
   I tried a few ways but always got bad data reply.
2. Using {sort} and define sort string with special characters
   How would that work with WebClient? I tried the following and it did not work.

   String DPCOMP="{Component="kafka"}";

   Mono responseMono = this.webClient.get()
   .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
   .queryParam("query",
   "(sum(sa_cluster_health{DPCOMP}))", DPCOMP)
   .build())
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(PrometheusResponse.class);

Thanks.

Comment: tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178910/spring-webclient-illegalargumentexception-not-enough-variables-to-expand-comm     it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I eventually make it work by implementing both:

1. disable Encoding (setting to NONE)
2. use askii code (%ascii_code) in pace for all the ( ) / { } ' " in the uri
   and it worked.
   Ascii code can be obtained from
   https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html